# How to stop the sending of ICMP timestamps replies and requests?

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, icmp, nftables

**Woo, progress! Updated below!** I've been all over the internet looking for an answer to this one. I am using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Debian 11. The problem seems rather simple, just blocking ICMP timestamp requests and replies, but after hours of web browsing and trying 3 different solutions, none of them have worked. I have tried:

- Using ipchains, but that is now obsolete, so I looked for how to do it using iptables instead. I found [this tutorial](https://www.putorius.net/mitigate-icmp-timestamp-vulnerabilities.html) that suggests to use `iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type timestamp-request -j DROP`, but that gives the error `iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--icmp-type"`
- Apparently nftables is the updated version of iptables, so I tried following [this](https://kernelnewbies.org/nftables_examples) and using:

```
nft add table ip filter # create table. I would have needed to enter this, but the table was already created so I didn't have to. 
nft add chain ip filter INPUT { type filter hook input priority 0 \; } # create chain
nft insert rule ip filter INPUT icmp type timestamp-request counter drop
nft insert rule ip filter INPUT icmp type timestamp-reply counter drop
sudo systemctl start nftables
sudo systemctl enable nftables
#backup your old /etc/nftables.conf file first before continuing
sudo nft list ruleset > /etc/nftables.conf
```

- I tried adding the line `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0` to /etc/sysctl.conf as I saw [here](https://www.unix.com/linux/11290-linux-icmp-timestamp-requests.html)

My full /etc/nftables.conf looks like:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
flush ruleset

table ip nat {
        chain POSTROUTING {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 10.0.0.0/24 ip daddr != 10.0.0.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
                oifname "wlan0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
        }
}
table ip filter {
        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "wlan0" oifname "uap0" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "uap0" oifname "wlan0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }

        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                icmp type timestamp-reply counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
                icmp type timestamp-request counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        }
}
```

Still no luck. How do I block or disable my system from replying to timestamps?

Edit: To test if the Pi will respond to timestamp requests, I run `nmap -v -v -v -PP 10.6.74.84`, where 10.6.74.84 is the Pi's IP, and then I look for "Host is up, received timestamp-reply ttl 63 (0.0057s latency)." in the results.

And breakthrough! /etc/nftables.conf is as above, but running `sudo nft list ruleset` prints:

```
table ip nat {
        chain POSTROUTING {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 10.0.0.0/24 ip daddr != 10.0.0.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
                oifname "wlan0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
        }
}
table ip filter {
        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "wlan0" oifname "uap0" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "uap0" oifname "wlan0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }

        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
```

It's different! Missing some lines! So the ruleset is not updated to match what is most recent in the .conf file, or something? Going to do a bit of research.

Comment: Check if your router has this functionality. Most often, even on consumer routers, there's an option somewhere to block PING requests from WAN to shield onesself. Also, if you block on your pi, its possible your router still replies to WAN ICMP packages, and I'm sure its that last bit that you are trying to stop, no?

Comment: `systemctl start nftables`. Depending on your distro and ruleset file(s), this might empty/undo what you have done with `nft add`.

Comment: Also no one knows how exactly you have no luck. Provide details on how you have been testing (e.g. utility / full command that was used to send the request) and the results / dumps / logs, with perhaps also the IP configuration (to make the context clear, like whether you should really be filtering "input" traffics or maybe actually,  "forward" traffics).

Comment: Ok! Updated, thank you!

Comment: What's the output of `nft --debug netlink add rule ip filter INPUT icmp type timestamp-request drop` and how does `nft list ruleset` look right after running that?

Comment: Also, do rules like `tcp dport 1234 drop` and/or `meta l4proto 1 @th,0,8 13 drop` on the other hand get added/applied successfully?